# Создать объект производного класса с передачей параметров в конструктор базового класса

Tags: c++, классы, конструктор, параметры

Если не затруднит, утолите мой интерес, пожалуйста!

Есть базовый и производный классы с атрибутами `a`, `b` - у базового и `c`, `d` - у производного.
Умею создавать объект производного класса с параметрами для производного (атрибуты базового = по умолчанию):

```
class Base
{
public:
    int a, b;

    Base() : a(1), b(1) { } // Base по умолчанию: a = 1, b = 1
    Base(int _a, int _b) : a(_a), b(_b) { } // Base с параметрами: a = 2, b = 2
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    int c, d;

    Derived() : c(10), d(10) { } // Derived по умолчанию: a = 1, b = 1, c = 10, d = 10
    Derived(int _c, int _d) : c(_c), d(_d) { } // Derived с параметрами: a = 1, b = 1, c = 20, d = 20
};

int main()
{
    Derived d1; // a = 1; b = 1; c = 10; d = 10
    Derived d2(20, 20); // a = 1; b = 1; c = 20; d = 20
}
```

1) Как создать объект производного класса по умолчанию, передав какие-нибудь аргументы в конструктор базового класса?

2) Как создать объект производного класса с параметрами, передав какие-нибудь аргументы в конструктор базового класса?

Должен ли я для этого описать в классе "Derived" ещё два конструктора?:

```
Derived() : Base(2, 2), c(10), d(10) { } // Base с параметрами, Derived по умолчанию
Derived(int _c, int _d) : Base(2, 2), c(_c), d(_d) { } // Base с параметрами, Derived с параметрами
```

В таком случае, что надо написать в main() для создания всех вариаций экземпляров производного класса?

```
int main()
{
    Derived d1; // a = 1; b = 1; c = 10; d = 10
    Derived d2(20, 20); // a = 1; b = 1; c = 20; d = 20
    // объект d3, у которого: a = 2, b = 2, c = 10, d = 10
    // объект d4, у которого: a = 2, b = 2, c = 20, d = 20
}
```

Знаю, что можно переприсвоить значения этим переменным посредством такого конструктора:

```
Derived(int _a, int _b, int _c, int _d) : a(_a), b(_b), c(_c), d(_d) { }
```

и затем в main() передать аргументы:

```
Derived d4(2, 2, 20, 20);
```

Но интересует именно вопрос о передаче аргументов конструктору базового во время создания объекта производного. Как такое реализовать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Как создать объект производного класса по умолчанию, передав какие-нибудь аргументы в конструктор базового класса?

А **где** вы их планируете передать? Конструктор по умолчанию - он без параметров. Так что это только "через голову" конструктора, типа, через глобальную переменную - но это же ужасно некрасиво...

> 2) Как создать объект производного класса с параметрами, передав какие-нибудь аргументы в конструктор базового класса?

Непонятно, как это трактовать. Вы передаете параметры для конструктора базового в производном? Запросто:

```
Derived(int d1, int d2, int b1, int b2):Base(b1, b2),...... // прочая инициализация
```

Вы хотите передавать параметры в базовый конструктор, но создавать при этом объект производного? Надеюсь, это я просто неверно вас понял, потому что по-хорошему ну не должен знать базовый класс о производных. Такой вот гулящий это родитель... :)

Comment: Второй вопрос прояснился - добавить подходящий конструктор, спасибо! По поводу первого: хочу создать производный, у которого поля `a` и `b` будут инициализированы в конструкторе базового с параметрами, а поля `c` и `d` будут инициализированы в конструкторе производного по умолчанию. То есть должен быть создан объект (как в первом посте) `d4`, у которого: `a = 2; b = 2; c = 10; d = 10`

Comment: извиняюсь, не успел поправить: Должен быть создан объект (как в первом посте) `d3`...

Comment: Я немного не о том. Как в идеале вы себе представляете описание такого объекта? Ну вот `Derived d4;` - куда тут засунуть 2 и 2? А если вы хотите `Derived d4(2,2);`, то вы уже вызываете конструктор не по умолчанию, а с параметрами... Поэтому и спрашиваю - как бы вы хотели в идеале записать желаемое в своей программе (сейчас неважно, можно это или нет - просто, что бы вы хотели?)

Comment: Я думал, что в `main()`, при создании производного объекта, можно в аргументах написать вызов конструктора с параметрами для базового класса, но чтобы конструктор производного остался без параметров. Как-то вроде: `Derived d3(Base(2, 2));` или `Derived d3(Base::Base(2, 2));`. Но у меня это не сработало. Иначе не представляю, поэтому и создал этот вопрос)

Comment: Ну так добавьте конструктор от Base!  https://ideone.com/98Qieg

Answer (score 1):

Я посмотрел ваши комментарии к ответу. Наверное, можно решить так - передавать в `Derived` параметры для `Base`

```
Derived(int a, int b, int с = 10, int d = 10)
:Base(a,b),c(c),d(d) { ... }
```

Вызов `Derived d(a,b)` вызовет конструктор `Base(a,b)` и выполнит действия со значениями по умолчанию `c` и `d`.

Беда только, что у вас будет коллизия с простым конструктором `Derived(c,d)`. Можете добавлять дополнительный параметр какого-то специально разработанного типа, или сделать фаблики объектов.

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что для такого необходимо добавлять дополнительный параметр, по которому будет определяться какой конструктор вызывать. Но это в голове представлялось как-то "костыльно", поэтому создал вопрос - вдруг есть правильный способ сделать это. Чтобы, как раз, и коллизии эти не возникали.